# Fill comboBox with SELECT results

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, windows-forms-designer

I want to populate a combo box with the results of a `SELECT` query.

It shows rows in the combobox but all are : System.Data.DataRow

The results of the `SELECT` is stored in a datatable.

```
string ChaineDeSelction = "SELECT fir_mdnt FROM -- WHERE fir_aktiv = 1 AND EXISTS(select firbpv_fir from --)";
        OdbcConnection MyConnec = new OdbcConnection(MyConnString);       
        MyConnec.Open();
        OdbcCommand MyComm = new OdbcCommand(ChaineDeSelction, MyConnec);
        DataTable.Load(MyComm.ExecuteReader());

        _cb_Societe.DataSource = DataTable; <--- I tried this way the the foreach .Add way but both return the same.

        foreach(DataRow Ligne in DataTable.Rows)
        {
            _cb_Societe.Items.Add(Ligne);
        }
```

I also have a DataGridView filled with the same

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use need to learn about DisplayMember and ValueMember properties of combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about the following way:

```
 string ChaineDeSelction = "SELECT fir_mdnt FROM -- WHERE fir_aktiv = 1 AND EXISTS(select firbpv_fir from --)";
        OdbcConnection MyConnec = new OdbcConnection(MyConnString);
        MyConnec.Open();
        OdbcCommand MyComm = new OdbcCommand(ChaineDeSelction, MyConnec);
        OdbcDataReader reader = MyComm.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            _cb_Societe.Items.Add(reader[0]);
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify which field you want to display using `DisplayMember` Property and not the whole row as you have done. And you need to save to a `DataTable` your `Reader`.

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Load(MyComm.ExecuteReader());
 _cb_Societe.DataSource = dt;
 _cb_Societe.DisplayMember = "fir_mdnt";
```